# How to wrap notifies or subscribes in chef cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, wrapper, cookbook, recipe

In *keepalived* cookbook there is such definition of *keepalived* service resource:

```
service "keepalived" do
    supports :restart => true
    action [:enable, :start]
    subscribes :restart, "template[keepalived.conf]"
end
```

It's probably ok for most people but I don't want to restart *keepalived* in case of small changes in configuration. Restarting will cause moving ip's from master server to slave and so on - on CentOS it's enough to reload service.

So I started wrapping it in my cookbook like this:

```
begin
    r = resources(:service => "keepalived")
    r.supports :restart => true, :reload => true
    r.subscribes :reload, "service[keepalived]"
rescue Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
    Chef::Log.warn "could not find service to override!"
end
```

But this called restart and then reload of service:

```
 Recipe: keepalived::default
     - restart service service[keepalived]
     - reload service service[keepalived]
```

I found here: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/78ba88287781667e4aa344bc4ceff280fa7ac466/lib/chef/resource.rb#L316
that *subscribes* is converted into *notifies* so I tried to wrap notifies on *template[keepalived.conf]* with same result and without success ;/

Can any one help with that?

Comment: I guess you have to remove it from the resource collection, but I'm just not sure, how to do this.

Comment: Sounds like you could make an improvement request on the `keepalived` cookbook, or send them a pull request with the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "override" subscribe or notify calls.  You can, however, remove them from the notification stack, but it's not a pretty thing to do.  The `run_context` object has a collection of immediate and delayed notifications.  You'll have to get at that, search through it, and remove the offending notification.  And, since very little of that is in the public API, you'll risk it breaking with each update of Chef.  Your best bet is to put in a PR with the cookbook asking the restart to be changed to reload, or at least giving the option of changing it to a reload.

I will add exact example here:

```
n = run_context.delayed_notifications('template[keepalived.conf]')
n.first.action = :reload
```

Additional tips:

- use `notifies_immediately` or `delayed_notifications` for exact type of notyfication,
- `subscribes` is silently converted into `notifies` on target resource, so you have to always overwrite proper `notifes` object.

Comment: Thanks for this tip - it's exactly what I've done just before you answered :-)

Example code looks like this:

    n = run_context.delayed_notifications('template[keepalived.conf]')
    n.first.action = :reload

I agree that PR to original project will be best solution but because of enforced need to sign CLA I have no permission to do that right now.

Comment: Oh, what a pain.  I had to deal with that once upon a time. It was annoying.  But I'm glad that worked for you.  I hadn't even considered changing the action to :reload vs just deleting the notification.